# Garbage collector in JAVA sp

Tags: java

My question is about where can I find the GC specification. I tried to looking for in [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html) but it doesn't contain neither garbage nor collector keyword. So where does Oracle specify working principles of GC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's the following [Java Garbage Collection Basics](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

Which comes directly from Oracle's website. It contains multiple sections regarding GC and even though the title explicitly says basic, it's gone into quite some detail. Hope this helps. If you need something more detailed just ask. However you may have to go somewhere outside of Oracle's websites

Answer (score 1):

Here's good document from Oracle. See [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) for brief details about the same.